# How I can remove the last(newest) article in Views lists (like Grid, HTML List unformatted and ...) in Drupal 7

Tags: list, drupal, module, view

I'm new to Drupal 7 and working on a news portal project. I have a list view of all published article which ordered by date those created, But the views module shows all of the published article and I want that doesn't show the last one (newest in other word) because I want to show it in a different block. I can't find any related configuration for doing that.

Please help me.
TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an offset in the Pager section (middle section) when editing the View itself. Set it to 1 and the first entry will get skipped.

[image: Enter 1 in the Offset field to skip the first one]